# Quantlib, difficulties reconciling yield to maturity of bond cashflows

Tags: python, pyomo, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I am having problems reconciling the yield to maturity calculation for a stream of cashflows.

In the code,  I take vectors of dates and amounts to create a BondLeg, to which I assign a dirty_value.

I use ql.Cashflows.yieldRate to calculate an Annually Compounding and Continuous Compounding Yield to Maturity.

I generate the yearFraction for the dates using the same daycount basis used to calculate the yields.

I then use a PYOMO Non Linear Optimization Solver (ipopt) to solve for the yield to maturities using the yearfractions, cashflow amounts and dirty_value.

The PYOMO annually compounding yield is within 1bp of the quantlib yield.  However,  the quantlib continuously compounded yield is 13bp higher than the PYOMO yield.

Code from my Jupyter Notebook is below:

### Imports

```
import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql

import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(30,6,2023)
```

### Cashflows and Dirty Value

```
dates = [ql.Date(14,11,2023), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2024), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2025), 
         ql.Date(16,11,2026), 
         ql.Date(15,11,2027), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2028), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2029), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2030), 
         ql.Date(14,11,2031), 
         ql.Date(15,11,2032)]

amounts = [84070, 
           84070, 
           84070, 
           84537.05555555558,
           65131.50532953604,
           65131.50532953604,
           65312.930135468014,
           65312.930135468014,
           65312.930135468014,
           1065494.3549413998]


dirty_val = 1050876.388888889
```

### Quantlib Code

```
BondLeg = ql.Leg([ql.SimpleCashFlow(amt, dt) for dt,amt in zip(dates,amounts)])

ql_ra = ql.CashFlows.yieldRate(BondLeg, dirty_val, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Compounded, ql.Annual, True)
ql_rc = ql.CashFlows.yieldRate(BondLeg, dirty_val, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Compounded, ql.Continuous, True)
```

### Use Quantlib to generate YearFractions

```
year_fracs = [ql.Actual365Fixed().yearFraction(ql.Date(30,6,2023),dt) for dt in dates]

periods = np.array([frac for frac in year_fracs])
p_int = np.int_(periods)
p_frac = periods - p_int

amount_vec = np.array(amounts)
```

### Calculate using PYOMO Solver

#### Annually Compounding Yield

```
model_ra = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Decision Variables
model_ra.ra = pyo.Var(domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.05)
ra = model_ra.ra


# Objective Function

def ra_objective_rule(model_ra):
    
    return (amount_vec.dot(1/(((1+ra)**p_int)* (1+(ra*p_frac)))) - dirty_val)**2

model_ra.objf = pyo.Objective(rule=ra_objective_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

# Constraints


Solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')

results_ra = Solver.solve(model_ra)

print(results_ra)
print(f'Objective Function = {model_ra.objf()}')
print(f'ra = {ra()}')
```

#### Continuously Compounding Yield

```
model_rc = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Decision Variables
model_rc.rc = pyo.Var(domain = pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.05)
rc = model_rc.rc


# Objective Function

def rc_objective_rule(model_rc):
     
    return (amount_vec.dot(np.array([pyo.exp(-p*rc) for p in periods])) - dirty_val)**2
    
model_rc.objf = pyo.Objective(rule=rc_objective_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

# Constraints


Solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')

results_rc = Solver.solve(model_rc)

print(results_rc)
print(f'Objective Function = {model_rc.objf()}')
print(f'rc = {rc()}')
```

### Comparison of Results

```
print(f'QuantLib - Annually Compounded Rate : {ql_ra:.4%}')
print(f'QuantLib - Continuously Compounded Rate : {ql_rc:.4%}')

print(f'PYOMO - Annually Compounded Rate : {ra.value:.4%}')
print(f'PYOMO - Continuously Compounded Rate : {rc.value:.4%}')
```

QuantLib - Annually Compounded Rate : 7.3623%
QuantLib - Continuously Compounded Rate : 7.2315%

PYOMO - Annually Compounded Rate : 7.3526%
PYOMO - Continuously Compounded Rate : 7.1039%

Answer (score 0):

[Copying the answer from the QuantLib mailing list in case someone lands here from searching]

The call in the code above,

```
ql_rc = ql.CashFlows.yieldRate(BondLeg, dirty_val, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Compounded, ql.Continuous, True)
```

should instead be:

```
ql_rc = ql.CashFlows.yieldRate(BondLeg, dirty_val, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Continuous, ql.NoFrequency, True)
```

that is, `ql.Continuous` is not a frequency to associate to `ql.Compounded` but a compounding method in its own right.  The second call gives the result you expect.

Unfortunately, SWIG exports C++ enums as numeric constants with no particular type, so Python can't warn of the mismatch.  The first call was interpreting the numeric value of `ql.Continuous`, 2, as a semiannual compounding frequency.